# Count number of months using month names in ruby

Tags: ruby

In ruby how can i count number of months between two months using their names
Examples:

```
Feb to Oct => 9 
Dec to Mar => 4
Apr to Aug => 5
```

How can i achieve this ?

Comment: the question is not clear..add more detail..[check this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

```
def months_between( start_month, end_month)
  month_names = %w[ Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec ]
  (12 + month_names.index( end_month ) - month_names.index( start_month ) ) % 12 + 1
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use can use DateTime::strptime to get number represented the order of the month in a year. From there it should be easy

```
require 'date'
def distance(start_month, end_month)
  distance = DateTime.strptime(end_month,"%b").month - DateTime.strptime(start_month,"%b").month + 1 
  distance < 0 ? distance + 12 : distance      
end
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, Using this i will get 12 for Dec and 2 for Feb. Then how i will get count between them

Comment: if you want to deal with Dec this year to Feb next year for example, you can just add 12 if the result is negative: 2 - 12 + 1 = -9, -9 + 12 = 3

Comment: What if i get 12 (Dec) as a starting month

Comment: Using you code i will get 10 as a result for Dec to March

Comment: how do you call the function: distance("Dec","Mar") => 4

Answer (score 0):

You could define an array of 12 elements, containing your possible month names. Then, when you need to find the number of months between `month1` and `month2`, you need to find their indexes, possibly using a `hash`, like this:

```
#let month1 and month2 be the values
array = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
hash = Hash[array.map.with_index.to_a]    # => {"a"=>0, "b"=>1, "c"=>2}
#(hash[month2] + 12 - hash[month1]) % 12 should yield the desired result
```

However, the solution above does not deal with years. If `month1` is `'Jan'` and `month2` is `'Feb'`, then the result will be 1, regardless of the year of `month1` and the year of `month2`.

I am not fluent in Ruby, so my code might have errors in its syntax.

Comment: I need to consider the year as well because from Dec to Feb i should get 3 in result

Comment: That is already handled in my code. By considering the year I was meaning that from Dec 2012 to Feb 2014 you have 15 months, not 3 months. Please, test my code with Dec and Feb.

Comment: Do we need a +1 to the result as well ?

Comment: I do not understand the question

Answer (score 0):

If you have the month name then you can parse that month and get the sequence number of that month, like this:

```
require 'date'
month1 = Date.parse("Feb").month
month1 = Date.parse("Apr").month
```

Or You can use array of 12 month to find their sequence number.
And for counts between months:

```
result = ((month2 > month1) ? (month2 - month1) : (month1 - (month1 - month2)) + 1)
```

This will work for the sequence of the months. If the month1 id 'Dec' and month2 is 'Mar', then it will return count 4, not 9.